# Discordjs how to make a join message for any server?

Tags: javascript, join, discord.js

I know you can do it like this

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
   member.guild.channels.get('channelID').send("Welcome");  });
```

But then you have to specify a channelID.

[Welcome Channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGWYP.png)

All members join through this link onto the welcome channel. Is there a way that discordjs sends a join message where ever the user got invited? Example: A join link for general so the welcome message is in general.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `guildMemberAdd` event only returns a GuildMember object which doesn't seem to include a reference to the invite used. You can fetch all the generated invite links and guess which one was used, but I wouldn't recommend this option.

Here are three solutions I can think of:

### Use the System Message Channel

This channel can be defined in the server settings without enabling the "Random welcome message". You can find it in `Guild.systemChannelID`.

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=systemChannelID

[image: System Message Channel screenshot]

### With public bots, make this setting configurable by an admin

You can make your bot respond to a command that will allow an admin to select a channel, either by selecting the channel where the command was sent, or prompting a list of channels. This is not the most straightforward solution to implement, but this is the best in terms of UX for your users.

### With private bots, hardcode the channel ID

This one will be the easiest to implement if your using your bot privately in one server or a limited number of servers.

- Go into Discord settings
- Appearance
- Toggle "Developer mode" in the Avanced section
- Then right click on the desired channel, and Copy ID

Answer (score 0):

there is a event in the `Client()` class that called `guildMemberAdd`. It will return a `GuildMember` class that will store all informations about the newly joined member!

#### If you bot is private bot

then you can simple hard code your bot, by enable the [developer mode](https://www.discordia.me/en/developer-mode#:%7E:text=On%20Android%2C%20you%20can%20enable%20Developer%20Mode%20by,Developer%20Mode.%20Tap%20the%20toggle%20to%20enable%20it.) and right-click on the specific channel that you want your bot send **welcome messages** to, chose **get ID** and then paste the copied ID to `member.guild.channels.cache.get("THE_ID")` and then simple send the message.

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL_ID"); // Getting the channel
  if(channel){ // Checking if the channel exist
     channel.send(`Welcome ${member} to ${member.guild.name}`); //Send the message
  }
```

#### Else if your bot is public bot

Then you will need a setup command to helps others server owners setup their welcome message function with your bot.

You should need a **database** (google it, if you don't know) to store channel's IDs, then get the channel's ID and do the same thing that I mentioned before!